# how to stop tiles from spawning after a certain number in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, spawn

I have a script that spawns endless tiles (3D) and i want it to stop at after a certain number (e.g. 100) and at the end of the last tile (the 100th) i want to spawn an other prefab like a portal.
I have no clue how to do that.
Any answer i have found on google couldnt help.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
void Start()
{

    nextTileLocation = startPoint;
    nextTileRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    for (int i = 0; i < initSpawnNum; ++i) 
    {
        SpawnNextTile (i >= initNoObstacles);
    }


}


public void SpawnNextTile(bool spawnObstacles = true)
{
    var newTile = Instantiate (tile, nextTileLocation, nextTileRotation);

    var nextTile = newTile.Find ("Next Spawn Point");

    nextTileLocation = nextTile.position;
    nextTileRotation = nextTile.rotation;

    if (!spawnObstacles)
        return;

    var obstacleSpawnPoints = new List<GameObject> ();

    foreach (Transform child in newTile) {

        if (child.CompareTag ("ObstacleSpawn")) {

            obstacleSpawnPoints.Add (child.gameObject);
        }
    }

    if (obstacleSpawnPoints.Count > 0) {

        var spawnPoint = obstacleSpawnPoints [Random.Range (0, obstacleSpawnPoints.Count)];

        var spawnPos = spawnPoint.transform.position;

        var newObstacle = Instantiate (obstacle, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

        newObstacle.SetParent (spawnPoint.transform);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like pass in a bool to tell the function to spawn a portal.

```
void Start()
{
    nextTileLocation = startPoint;
    nextTileRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    for (int i = 0; i < initSpawnNum; ++i) 
    {
        // Pass in true for the last tile
        SpawnNextTile (i >= initNoObstacles, i == initSpawnNum - 1);
    }
}

public void SpawnNextTile(bool spawnObstacles = true, bool shouldSpawnPortal = false)
{
   //
}
```

Edit to show adding the tiles to a list:

```
class YourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();

    private void SpawnNextTile(bool spawnObstacles = true, bool shouldSpawnPortal = false)
    {
        var newTile = Instantiate (tile, nextTileLocation, nextTileRotation);
        tiles.Add(newTile);

        // The rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but where? the problrm is i dont know how to stop it and how to call ONLY the last prefabs location so i can spawn the portal.

Comment: i have thought about Lists but i dont know how to use it right know in my code. how can i add all the instantiated prefabs in a list?

Comment: If you instatiate the portal just after instantiating the tile, you'll be able to access the same position.

Comment: To add them to a list, you can do something like `private List<GameObject> tiles` and then `tiles.Add(newTile)`.

Comment: yes but then it would appear in every spawn of the prefab. i only need it at the end of the line

Comment: I'm confused. Surely if you use the bool I passed into the function in an if statement, you can stop the portal spawning until the last tile?

Comment: the list must be updated by itself. if i add them then i have to do 100 manual ads right?

Comment: Put the list add line in the `SpawnNextTile` function and then it's automatic.

Comment: yeah it could work but i need it to stop first sorry for making it hard to understan

Comment: What do you mean by "need it to stop"? Surely it would only run for the number of iterations defined by the for loop?

Comment: something like private<GameObject> tiles and then tiles.Add(SpawnNextTile)?

Comment: How is `initNoObstacles` defined? Also, I'll edit my answer to show the code to add the tiles to the list.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm wondering what number the variable represents, since you said the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: its existance is for the first 4 tiles to not instantiate any obstacles.

Comment: i  did that with the list and this is what i got after i run the game -------Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameController.SpawnNextTile (Boolean spawnObstacles) (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:59)
GameController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:43)------

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to initialise the list. You need to replace `private List<GameObject> tiles;` with `private List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();`. Also, it seems I wrote `initNoObstacles` when I meant `initSpawnNum`.

Comment: Dear friend the list now works great. I have know the tile instatiation code on a different function and i do an InvokeRepeating in the spawn fuction and works great. BUT whenever i do an if statement ( if(tilesSpawn <20) {CancelInvoke("spawntiles") ) then it doesnt spawn any tile from the beggining.